# RegEx (?='\\').*$ - Trying to get username from domain\username

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string like `domainA\userNamePaul`. I tried this regex `(?='\\').*$` but the out put is same as input. I need to get the username without the domain. Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why not just `split('\\')` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [Positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html),

```
(?<=\\).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nW5qZ0/3)

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  \\                       '\'
)                        end of look-behind
.*                       any character except \n (0 or more times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Comment: see the demo, it isn't. You could try this `[^\\]*$` also http://regex101.com/r/nW5qZ0/4

Comment: It works. Thanks so much for the prompt reply. I appreciate it.

Comment: @GreenCode, the answer provided works for your situation.  Maybe there is a problem with your implementation?

Answer (score 4):

I believe using regex is some kind of overkill here. You can simply split string by `\`:

```
string identity = "DOMAIN\\USER";
string user = identity.Split('\\').Last();
```

or even faster:

```
string user = identity.Substring(identity.IndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Comment: This is a better suggestion than the above, anyway, because it also returns the full username if it's *not* a Windows user, in systems where users can have domain-prefixed logins but can also *not*. :)